# PHP Parse iCal Reminder String

Tags: php, string, parsing, icalendar

I'm currently working on parsing iCal reminder strings, similar to: `-P14DT0H0M0S`

Using PHP, how might I be able to parse the elements of the string so that if I had:

```
<?
 $reminder = "-P14DT0H0M0S"  // somehow output to show "-2 weeks" or eve "-14 days"

             //  OR  //

 $reminder = "-P0DT3H0M0S"  // somehow output to "-3 hours" 

 // etc...
```

Any help on this would be great.  I'm kind of stuck on where to begin.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the format, and there's almost certainly a library available for this, but it looks like a simple regex would do the job here.

Something like:

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/^-P(\d+)DT(\d+)H(\d+)M(\d+)S$/', $reminder, $matches))
{
  // matched pattern, elements captured with () will be stored in $matches[1..]
  $days = $matches[1];
  $hours = $matches[2]; 
  $minutes = $matches[3];
  $seconds = $matches[4];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the background of your project or your end result is, but this may help:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/libical/

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar can drop time part completely and return something like '-P7D' so I have tweaked
**therefromhere**'s regexp to deal with that.

```
preg_match('/^-P(\d+)DT?(\d+)?H?(\d+)?M?(\d+)?S?$/', $reminder, $matches);
```